# Can I know how to fix this error i encounter when running npx react-native run-android

Tags: react-native, npx

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-pdf:processDebugManifest'.

> Failed to calculate the value of task ':react-native-pdf:processDebugManifest' property 'packageOverride'.
> Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'.
> > Package Name not found in C:\Users\Kaveesha_112347\Documents\Projects\celcom-life-app\node_modules\react-native-pdf\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-pdf:processDebugManifest'.

> Failed to calculate the value of task ':react-native-pdf:processDebugManifest' property 'packageOverride'.
> Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'.
> > Package Name not found in C:\Users\Kaveesha_112347\Documents\Projects\celcom-life-app\node_modules\react-native-pdf\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Are you facing this issue after installing a specific library?

Comment: so accidentally the package value of the react-native-pdf has been deleted. fixed it thank you :)